# Linux console: "Unable to get valid context for..."

Tags: linux, ssh, selinux

I have the warning `Unable to get valid context for crimbo` appearing at login, and I have not been able to fix it...

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-83-generic x86_64)                                                                       

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com                                                                                              
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com                                                                                      
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage                                                                                         

0 packages can be updated.                                                                                                              
0 updates are security updates.                                                                                                         


Unable to get valid context for crimbo                                                                                                  
Last login: Fri Jun 30 00:29:56 2017 from 65.52.184.164
```

I believe this is not specific to Ubuntu. I have created a . autorelabel at the root of the drive and rebooted the system to make SELinux rebuild the labels of the entire filesystem as directed [here](http://e9p.net/ssh-unable-get-valid-context-name), but it has not made any difference. The autorelabel must of taken place as the file is no longer there.

Do you have any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend checking your SELinux user mapping if you haven't already. I came across a similar error on the graphical side of a CentOS 7x box. It was because the user I was currently trying to log in as was mapped to the "sysadm_u" user. You can confirm this by running `semanage login -l`. The fix was to run
 `setsebool xdm_sysadm_login on`
and in your case, probably 
`setsebool ssh_sysadm_login on` 
could help as well.

Comment: Running `semanage login -l` returns `ValueError: SELinux policy is not managed or store cannot be accessed.`

Comment: I turned off 'root' login - Are you suggesting that might be why?