# Ubuntu - SSH - Unable to get valid context for <user>

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, selinux

I'm seeing a strange warning when I log onto my Ubuntu box from my Mac, "`Unable to get valid context for <user>`".  I don't remember when this started, or what could've possibly changed to cause this.  I haven't experienced any adverse effects as of yet, I'm just unsure why this message appears now.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-104-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


Unable to get valid context for meanwhileinhell
Last login: Tue Dec 19 10:31:44 2017 from 192.168.2.1
```

```
/var/log/auth.log

sshd[6147]: Accepted publickey for meanwhileinhell from 192.168.2.1 port 57194 ssh2: RSA SHA256:<key>
sshd[6147]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user meanwhileinhell by (uid=0)
systemd-logind[780]: New session 6 of user meanwhileinhell.
sshd[6147]: pam_selinux(sshd:session): Unable to get valid context for meanwhileinhell
sshd[6177]: error: ssh_selinux_getctxbyname: Failed to get default SELinux security context for meanwhileinhell
sshd[6147]: error: ssh_selinux_getctxbyname: Failed to get default SELinux security context for meanwhileinhell
sshd[6147]: error: ssh_selinux_setup_pty: security_compute_relabel: Invalid argument
```

```
$ sestatus -v

SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             ubuntu
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      30

Process contexts:
Current context:                system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0
Init context:                   system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0

File contexts:
Controlling terminal:           system_u:object_r:devpts_t:s0
/etc/passwd                     system_u:object_r:file_t:s0
/etc/shadow                     system_u:object_r:file_t:s0
/bin/bash                       system_u:object_r:file_t:s0
/bin/login                      system_u:object_r:file_t:s0
/bin/sh                         system_u:object_r:file_t:s0 -> 
system_u:object_r:file_t:s0
/sbin/agetty                    system_u:object_r:file_t:s0
/sbin/init                      system_u:object_r:file_t:s0 -> 
system_u:object_r:file_t:s0
/usr/sbin/sshd                  system_u:object_r:file_t:s0
```

I know very little about SELinux so am hesitant to go ahead and just run unknown commands, but I'd be very grateful if someone could help me understand what this means.  I found this SO question [Linux console: "Unable to get valid context for..."](https://superuser.com/questions/1224284/linux-console-unable-to-get-valid-context-for) but it doesn't provide anything useful.

```
$ semanage login -l
ValueError: SELinux policy is not managed or store cannot be accessed.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ semanage login -l
```

This fails because you need to do it as root. It works when I use "sudo". I don't know if that puts you any closer to the answer; I stumbled across your question while also trying to find out how to resolve this!